# Elasticsearch documents are dropped on bulk insert

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following situation:
Logstash with a JDBC input connector and an Elasticsearch output connector.
The data is loaded initially into the ES, meaning the indices which are filled do not exist prior to the Logstash load.
Logstash creates the indices based on mapping templates.
Logstash and ES are in version 7.17.0.

This scenario worked perfectly fine until recently.

**Issue**

The indexing works perfectly fine until around 1 mio documents. Then indexing of new documents slows down rapidly and the number of deleted documents oscillates immensely. It increases a lot and drops frequently.

I am aware that documents are deleted as part of an update operation and this was previously already the case. But the deleted documents count mostly increased and did not oscillate to that extend.
Before the issue occurred the situation at the end of the load was around 8 mio docs.count and around 3 mio as docs.deleted. At the moment the number stays at around 1.2 mio.

The scenario is deployed on two environments and only one of the environments shows this behavior. Both have the same source and Logstash configuration. The environments differ in their ES instance. Both instances are configured equally.

The disk space is fine and there are no error in the ES log.
I also can confirm that the Logstash is running fine and is constantly sending bulk requests to the ES.

There is another thread in which someone mentioned that ES is dropping documents in overload scenarios. I could not find any proof for that behavior but this would at least be a good explanation for what I am experiencing:
[Documents are automatically getting deleted in Elasticsearch after insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218812/documents-are-automatically-getting-deleted-in-elasticsearch-after-insertion)

**Time series of the metrics**

```
TIME 1230:
health status index                     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   myindex                   LLC8qxSWTWyO1U25Olljlg   1   1    1182676       166056    642.3mb        642.3mb

TIME 1240:
health status index                     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   myindex                   LLC8qxSWTWyO1U25Olljlg   1   1    1182676       533339    946.9mb        946.9mb

TIME 1300:
health status index                     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   myindex                   LLC8qxSWTWyO1U25Olljlg   1   1    1182676       349747    701.9mb        701.9mb

TIME 1400:
health status index                     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   myindex                   LLC8qxSWTWyO1U25Olljlg   1   1    1182678       467651        1gb            1gb

TIME 1430:
health status index                     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   myindex                   LLC8qxSWTWyO1U25Olljlg   1   1    1182678       693906        1gb            1gb
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually after analyzing the Logstash in detail we realized that Logstash is not updating it's meta data for some reason and hence it sends the same data in an endless loop.
The ES works perfectly fine and this also explains the oscillating deleted documents.

Seems to be a network issue which we need to investigate further.